# How to get tableview cell data and save it to database?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a small JavaFX application that stores data into a tableview and then allows the user to manipulate the data. My current issue is saving the cell data from the tableview into the database.

I do not know how to store the entire cell data and then update it into SQL using update query based on the Primary Key, which in my case is the Truck # column. The main data I need to store is from the ComboBox and the CheckBox, but it wouldn't hurt to get the other columns as well, along with how to get the corresponding Truck #. So my goal is for the user to be able to enter some value into the comboBox and then click the save option from the menu and have that cell information get stored into the database, not to use textfields and individually update items.

Whatever is written into the ComboBox Column is what should be saved https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGtNP.jpg

I already have an update feature where the user can enter a specific Truck # and edit the other fields which will update the database, but I need everything currently in the TableView to be saved to the database.

```java
public class TruckInfo {

    private CheckBox In;
    private CheckBox Out;
    private String truck_id;
    private Integer year;
    private String pallet_num;
    private String tr_class;
    private ComboBox<String> msgBox;
    private String combo;


    public TruckInfo() {
        this.truck_id = "";
        this.year = 0;
        this.pallet_num = "";
        this.tr_class = "";
        this.combo = "";

    }

    public TruckInfo(String truck_id, Integer year, String pallet_num, String tr_class, String combo) {
        this.In = new CheckBox();
        In.getStyleClass().add("check-box-style-in");

        this.Out = new CheckBox();
        Out.getStyleClass().add("check-box-style-out");

        this.truck_id = truck_id;
        this.year = year;
        this.pallet_num = pallet_num;
        this.tr_class = tr_class;
        this.msgBox = new ComboBox<String>();
        msgBox.getItems().addAll("Kenosha", "Keep Local", "Do Not Use", "Shop");
        msgBox.setEditable(true);
        msgBox.setValue(combo);
        this.combo = combo;

    }

    public String getCombo() {
        return combo;
    }

    public void setCombo(String combo) {
        this.combo = combo;
    }

    public CheckBox getIn() {
        return In;
    }
    public void setIn(CheckBox in) {
        In = in;
    }
    public CheckBox getOut() {
        return Out;
    }
    public void setOut(CheckBox out) {
        Out = out;
    }

    public String getTruck_id() {
        return truck_id;
    }

    public void setTruck_id(String truck_id) {
        this.truck_id = truck_id;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getPallet_num() {
        return pallet_num;
    }

    public void setPallet_num(String pallet_num) {
        this.pallet_num = pallet_num;
    }

    public String getTr_class() {
        return tr_class;
    }

    public void setTr_class(String tr_class) {
        this.tr_class = tr_class;
    }

    public ComboBox<String> getMsgBox() {
        return msgBox;
    }

    public void setMsgBox(ComboBox<String> msgBox) {
        this.msgBox = msgBox;
    }


}
```

```java
public class TruckController implements Initializable {

    private TruckDAO dao;

    ObservableList<TruckInfo> obList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

        dao = new TruckDAO();

        try {
            Connection connection = new DBConnect().getConnection();

            ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM truck");

            while (rs.next()) {
                obList.add(new TruckInfo(rs.getString("truck_id"), rs.getInt("year"),
                        rs.getString("pallet_num"), rs.getString("class"), rs.getString("message")));
            }
            System.out.println("Database Connected");
            connection.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(TruckController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }

        inColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("In"));
        outColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Out"));
        truckNumColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("truck_id"));
        yearColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("year"));
        palletNumColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pallet_num"));
        trClassColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("tr_class"));
        msgColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("msgBox"));

        truckTable.setItems(obList);

    }


    @FXML
    public TableView<TruckInfo> truckTable;

    @FXML
    public MenuBar menuBar;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<TruckInfo, CheckBox> inColumn;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<TruckInfo, CheckBox> outColumn;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<TruckInfo, String> truckNumColumn;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<TruckInfo, Integer> yearColumn;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<TruckInfo, String> palletNumColumn;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<TruckInfo, String> trClassColumn;

    @FXML
    public TableColumn<TruckInfo, ComboBox<String>> msgColumn;
```

```java
public void save(ActionEvent event) {

        TruckInfo savedData = new TruckInfo();

        ObservableList<TruckInfo> tableData = truckTable.getItems();

        List <List<String>> arrList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < truckTable.getItems().size(); i++ ) {
            savedData = truckTable.getItems().get(i);
            arrList.add(new ArrayList<>());
            arrList.get(i).add(savedData.getTruck_id());
            arrList.get(i).add(""+savedData.getYear());
            arrList.get(i).add(""+savedData.getPallet_num());
            arrList.get(i).add(""+savedData.getTr_class());
            arrList.get(i).add(""+savedData.getCombo());

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrList.get(i).size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(arrList.get(i).get(j));  
            }
        }

        String id = savedData.getTruck_id();
        int year = savedData.getYear();
        String pallet = savedData.getPallet_num();
    String clas = savedData.getTr_class();

        String msg = savedData.getCombo();

        String idSave = savedData.getTruck_id();

        System.out.println(msg);
        System.out.println(idSave);

        String sql = "UPDATE truck SET message = ? WHERE truck_id = '" + idSave + "'";

        try {
            Connection connection = new DBConnect().getConnection();

            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            statement.setString(1, msg);

            statement.execute();
            statement.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

The result should be users entering some text into the ComboBox column and then saving before exiting the application, so that the text can be re-accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer if anyone is wondering.

```
    public void save(ActionEvent event) {

        TruckInfo savedData = new TruckInfo();

        for(int i = 0; i < truckTable.getItems().size(); i++) {
            savedData = truckTable.getItems().get(i);
            String idSave = (String) truckNumColumn.getCellObservableValue(savedData).getValue();
            ComboBox<String> msg = (ComboBox<String>) msgColumn.getCellObservableValue(savedData).getValue();

            System.out.println(msg.getValue());
            System.out.println(idSave);

            String sql = "UPDATE truck SET message = ? WHERE truck_id = '" + idSave + "'";

            try {
                Connection connection = new DBConnect().getConnection();

                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

                statement.setString(1, msg.getValue());

                statement.execute();
                statement.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }   

    }
```

The answer lies in the getCellObservableValue().getValue()